# Strange nullpointer exception error when i use a List

Tags: java, list, nullpointerexception

i am using a List of `<Friend>`, Friend is a class that i have with some info about a person, name, desc, etc...

ok, this is the code on the start of the class:

```
private List<Friend> friends;
```

and later... in a method of the class:

```
Friend a = new Friend("Pablo SáeZ", "Total", "39.68333", "-0.32667", new Date());
friends.add(a);
```

ok, i have the nullpointerexception on the line `friends.add(a);`

can someone explain why?

thanks

Comment: I've rollbacked your edit. Please press `Ask Question` button if you have a new question. Don't edit an exising one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because you haven't initialized `friends` yet. It's still `null`.

You need to initialize it before using.

```
friends = new ArrayList<Friend>();
```

A common place to do this job is the class' constructor.

Comment: No.... it doesn't works.... i put this: friends = new List<Friend>();

eclipse says: cannot instantiate the type List<Friend>



lol, 7 guys up the wrong answer

Comment: Put on your glasses. I said [`ArrayList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), not [`List`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html). You obviously can't instantiate an interface. I'd suggest to stop temporarily with this all and redo the Java basics by a decent tutorial/book :)

Comment: but i dont wanna use arrayList.... i can't do with List? why ? i think i used List sometimes in the past, some years ago when i study

Comment: No, it's an interface, not a class. You need to use one of its implementations. `ArrayList` is the best choice for this particular purpose. Just do `List<Friend> friends = new ArrayList<Friend>()`. See also the [Collections tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html).

Comment: I think you've to learn about polymorphism and other basic OOP concepts as well :)

Comment: upsss sec using arraylist my program is still crashing, i will check logcat, let me some mins

Comment: You're welcome. In the future, try not to act like a stupid moron with your "lol" thing :) I almost deleted the answer.

Comment: first element of arraylist is 0 or 1 ?

Comment: i get arrayindexoutofbounds exception here: string a = friends.get(i).getUsername();

i is on a for (atm i is 0 when crash)

Comment: 11-17 22:48:05.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(754): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid location 1, size is 1

Comment: mate, i make some changes on the first post, read it plz, my error is in this line:

USERS[i]=friends.get(i+1).getUsername();

Comment: You have 1 element in your friends List but you're trying to access the second element? Java Arrays start from 0.

Comment: @Android: that's a completely different problem. Your `NullPointerException` problem is been solved. Press the `Ask Question` button at right top if you stucks with `IndexOutOfBoundsException` even after reading the aforelinked Collections tutorial.